# Available datasets for HTTP headers

Tags: internet

I would like to know if there are any publicly available datasets with HTTP header data, such as URI, user-agent, referer, content-length, etc--

I've tried searching with the usual keywords to no avail. All network flow data I have chanced upon are flow-based, or are incomplete- one only provides the host + URI, whilst the other hashes the URI used due to privacy issues.

Comment: I would be interested in this as well. Specifically I would want to know about a dataset containing headers *sent by users to websites*.

Comment: BTW [The HTTP Archive](https://httparchive.org/) is interesting and somewhat related